# If $T$ is a linear operator on the vector space $V$ , we have to prove $\ker(T - \lambda I)^k \subset \ker(T - \lambda I)^{k+1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If $T$ is a linear operator on the vector space $V$ , we have to prove $\ker(T - \lambda I)^k \subset \ker(T - \lambda I)^{k+1}$.

**My Attempt:**  Let's suppose the matrix representation of the linear transformation $(T - \lambda I)$ is $A$. Then the matrix representation of the linear transformation $(T - \lambda I)^k$  and  $(T - \lambda I)^{k+1}$ will be  $A^k$   and $A^{k+1}$ .

Now as $A^k x = 0 \implies A^{k+1} x = 0$. we can say $\ker(T - \lambda I)^k \subset \ker(T - \lambda I)^{k+1}$.

Have I gone wrong somewhere ?

Comment: You're not wrong, but there really is no need to think about a matrix representation.

Comment: It is so easy. That is why I doubt and post the question here. I was thinking I am missing something big.

Comment: A detail that isn't explicitly stated here is that the reason $A^k x = 0 \implies A^{k+1}x = 0$ is because $A = T - \lambda I$ is a linear transformation, and linear transformations always map zero to zero. Therefore $A^{k+1}x = A(A^{k}x) = A(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v \in \ker(T- \lambda I)^k$. Then
\begin{align}
(T- \lambda I)^{k+1}v = (T- \lambda I)(T- \lambda I)^k v = 0.
\end{align}
Hence, $v \in \ker(T- \lambda I)^{k+1}$.